# how can i differentiate between scheduled call and HTTP call of the same function in java?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, scheduled-tasks

i have a get function in my microservice which essentially fetchs data from a database. this function is running as a scheduler (cron job) and also as an api end point which can be triggered from the UI.

```
@GetMapping(value = "getDataUI")
public String getDataUI() throws Exception {
  return service.getData(); // call to service layer
}
```

```
//service layer

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8 * * ?")
public String getData(){
// logic here //
}
```

i want to add some logic inside getData() which will only be executed when it is being triggered by the scheduler and the logic should be skipped when being called from the UI ("/getDataUI").

how can i do this? or is there a better way to implement what i am trying to do?

Comment: can you pass method parameters to getData()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve by  following way

- Refactoring of  cron job and service method
- Cron Job can have wrapper method to call Service method.
- Add parameter in service method

In above example:

1.Same as above for getDataUI

```
 @GetMapping(value = "getDataUI")
   public String getDataUI() throws Exception {

    --
      return service.getData("UI"); // call to service layer
    }
```

2. Removed schedule annotation from Service layer

   //service layer

   ```
    public String getData(String param){
       if(param=="CRON")
          //
       else 
        //
    }
   ```
3. Schedule Task

   ```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8 * * ?")
    public String getScheduleData(){
     //service.getData("CRON");

    }
   ```

Comment: the logic in my main function is pretty huge and complex and hencei did not want to create another function and pass all the values between the function. this helps keep my code clean. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please note the simple rules that we need to follow to annotate a method with `@Scheduled` are:

- the method should typically have a void return type (if not, the returned value will be ignored)
- the method should not expect any parameters

**Solution 1. Create two separate methods**

Keep it simple:

```java
public class DataService implements Service {

    public String getData() {
        return "Data";
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8 * * ?")
    public void performScheduler() {
        /*scheduler logic*/
        String data = getData();
        /* process data */
    }
}
```

**Solution 2. Create separate service for scheduler**

```java
public class SchedulerDataService {
    
    private Service service;

    public SchedulerDataService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8 * * ?")
    public void performScheduler() {
        /*scheduler logic*/
        String data = service.getData();
        /* process data */
    }
}
```